# Lost one of my tool bars in blender and can't get it back

Tags: selection-tools

The tool bar on the far right of my blender editor is gone. It is not the properties bar (toggled with n) or the tool shelf (toggled with t). What I am missing is the bar in which I can add modifiers and materials. I can't figure out how to get it back, please help.

Comment: can it be that you presses CTRL+space and maximized the 3dview area...? press it again, to verify

Answer (score 2):

My screen recording is a little messed up, but I am clicking and dragging the little triangle tab in the top right of the 3D Viewport to the left, then clicking and dragging the new triangle downward.

Set each of these new screen areas to the desired UI screen type.

[image]